# How to use a class from another module in a Zend Front Controller Plugin?

Tags: zend-framework

We are currently reorganising our application (based on Zend framework 1.11) into a modular structure and are running in to the problem that we need to be able to use resources within a module before the autoloader for that module has been registered.

For example, we have a front controller plugin to check the user's login status..

```
class Application_Plugin_LoginCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

        // ACL-lookup code which ultimately retrieves Othermodule_Model_User 
        // from session
        // Othermodule_Model_User is not defined
    }
}
```

We need `Othermodule_Model_User` to be available at this point but it seems that the autoloader for `Othermodule` will not be registered until the bootstrap sequence.

Similarly, this same issue prevents us using classes form any another module in any given module's bootstrap class.

What is the proper way to achieve this kind of setup in a Zend Framework application?

Bootstrapping is being done using Zend's application bootstrap and module bootstrap classes. I've included an example below - I don't think we're doing anything unusual.

Application bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initDb() {...}

    protected function _initConfig() {...}

    protected function _initLog() {...}

    protected function _initMvcStaticRoutes() {...}

    protected function _initRestRoute() {...}

    protected function _initTranslate() {...}

    public function _initActionHelpers() {...}

    public function _initViewHelpers() {...} 
}
```

Module bootstrap:

```
class Account_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap { 
    protected function _initTranslate() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The plugin is registered in the application config

```
resources.frontController.plugins.logincheck.class = "Application_Plugin_LoginCheck"
```

Comment: The module autoloaders should be registered during the bootstrap. The preDispatch method of a controller plugin runs long after this, so I'm unsure why you would be having this issue. What do your bootstrap classes look like?

Comment: Modules are usually used to separate The `C` and `V` concerns of the MVC paradigm, not to namespace your `M` (Application / Library) code.  Models will obviously be shared across your application's modules. Seeing some of your bootstrap(s)/file structure might help.

Comment: If I am going to be using one model in multiple modules, I usually push up higher into the `Application_` namespace, rather than leaving it in a single module namespace. Still, @TimFountain is right re: plugins - all of which run long after Bootstrap.

Comment: @TimFountain - I've added a summary of the bootstrap classes. I can't see what we're doing that would deviate too much from what the framework intends

Comment: @ficuscr - I was hoping to be able to be able to modularise all of the application code rather than just controller/view logic. Each module would contain a logically related set of MVC and other classes (something like Magento does) which could utilise classes from other modules when required. I don't need to be able to re-use these modules in other applications - anything for use in multiple projects I would put in library. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Are you doing some custom session storage stuff and storing `Othermodule_Model_User` in the session (rather than the userID)? That might be your problem, as PHP will try and autoload that class as soon as the session is initialized.

Comment: @TimFountain - yes, exactly that. I guess there's probably other sound reasons for not storing serialized objects in the session so I could change that. Hmm, even if I store only the User ID in the session I'll probably still want to do things in the main bootstrap that depend on Othermodule_Model_User which at this point won't yet be autoloadable. Maybe I'd be better moving some of the bootstrap logic into front controller plugins as everything will be bootstrapped by then.

Comment: `Othermodule_Model_User` will be autoloadable in the main bootstrap once your modules are initialized (and bootstrapped). So see if you can reorder some of the things in your main bootstrap class, so your session and other stuff are all initialized after the modules are.